# mat tool tip is not showing on data source

Tags: angular

I am using data source to display my data in table format, but when I am trying to use mat tool tip it is not working. How to use mat tool tip inside data source or there are any other alternative?

```html
      <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Actions">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <span
              (click)="deleteVideo(element, 'allVideos')"
              *ngIf="!element.isDeleted"
              matTooltip="Make video Inactive"
              aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over"
            >
              <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked />
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>
            </span>
            <span
              (click)="restoreVideo(element, 'allVideos')"
              *ngIf="element.isDeleted"
              matTooltip="Make video Inactive"
              aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over"
            >
              <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>
            </span>
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you please elaborate?